# How to deal with 5-spoked pole that is not E-pole?

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

[image: the example of such 5-spoked pole]

Hey folks! I'm still a beginner in topology but already know how to treat standard E-pole (the vertice where three planes intersect after extrusion). But what would you do in such situation when 5-pole is the place where 4 planes converge? I mean all-quads-topology for furthest subdivision

Comment: Poles are a concern only for C-C subdivision, and this doesn't look like an example built for C-C subdivision.  Can you provide a more real-world example demonstrating your problem?    In a general sense, you have to live with poles, and the best you can do is move them somewhere more planar.  But here, if I assume a slightly different model (cylinder, at least 8 sides, with inset cutout), you live with the 5-pole exactly as you have it, because moving it gives you bad edge flow, and there's no planar place to shunt it off to.

Comment: After all my atttempts I came to the same conclusion, but I wasn't sure cause I'm a beginner